# How to convert HoltWinter of R into one of Python

Tags: python, r, statsmodels, holtwinters

I have to convert the code of R that predicts the temperature into one of Python.
But the code of R was not made by someone, so I need a help.

In R,

```
ts.train <- ts(train["avg"], frequency=52, start=c(1,1))
holt <- as.numeric(forecast(HoltWinters(ts.train, seasonal="additive"), h=4)$mean
```

`train` data has the weekly data with a yearly cycle like below,

| yyyyuu | avg |
| --- | --- |
| 201201 | 23.6 |
| 201202 | 22.4 |

`yyyyuu` means the weekly number `uu` of year `yyyy`.

According to the implementation of `HoltWinters` in R,

```
HoltWinters(x, alpha = NULL, beta = NULL, gamma = NULL,
            seasonal = c("additive", "multiplicative"),
            start.periods = 2, l.start = NULL, b.start = NULL,
            s.start = NULL,
            optim.start = c(alpha = 0.3, beta = 0.1, gamma = 0.1),
            optim.control = list())
```

So, I think that `HoltWinters(ts.train, seasonal="additive")` is referred by HoltWinters model like below,

```
smoothing_level: 0.3,
smoothing_trend: 0.1,
smoothing_seasonal: 0.1,
method: ls

trend: add
seasonal: add
```

And I think that `ts(train["avg"], frequency=52, start=c(1,1))` means `seasonal_periods = 52`

So, I have implemented it like below in `Python`,

```
fit_exp = ExponentialSmoothing(train['avg'], trend='add', seasonal_periods=52, seasonal='additive').fit(
    smoothing_level=0.3,
    smoothing_trend=0.1,
    smoothing_seasonal=0.1,
    method = "ls"
fit_exp.forecast(4)
)
```

But the results between `R` and `Python` are different each other,
In `R`

```
20.857783
20.788399
20.928776
21.582850
```

In `Python`,

```
20.683062
20.941403
21.183668
21.927177
```

So, I have some questions about this,

1. In `R`, there is a code to make time-series like `ts.train <- ts(train["avg"], frequency=52, start=c(1,1))`, but In python, there is no code to make time-series data. is it affected to the model result?
2. If so, How should I implement to make time-series data? In train data, there are only two columns, `yyyyuu` and `avg`.
3. Are there another parameters to synchronize `R` Holtwinter with `PYthon` Holtwinter?

Thank you.

Comment: In the Python version you're setting `smoothing_level`, `smoothing_trend` and `smoothing_seasonal`, while in your corresponding R parameters (`alpha, beta, gamma`) are left free which means there are optimized  (by minimizing one step pred error).  Try to omit those smoothing parameters.

Comment: @RicVillalba Thank you. 
But when I deleted `smoothing_level`, `smoothing_trend` and `smoothing_seasonal`, Its result would be also different from `python` result. 
Does not the basic parameter of `HoltWinters` in `R`, "`optim.start = c(alpha = 0.3, beta = 0.1, gamma = 0.1)`" means `smoothing_level`, `smoothing_trend` and `smoothing_seasonal`?